# ADD/COPY files with sbt-native-packager's docker support

Tags: scala, sbt, docker, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager 1.0.0-M5 to create my docker image. I need to add a file that's not a source file or in the resource folder. My docker commands are as follows:

```
dockerCommands := Seq(
  Cmd("FROM", "myrepo/myImage:1.0.0"),
  Cmd("COPY", "test.txt keys/"), // <-- The failing part
  Cmd("WORKDIR", "/opt/docker"),
  Cmd("RUN", "[\"chown\", \"-R\", \"daemon\", \".\"]"),
  Cmd("USER", "daemon"),
  ExecCmd("CMD", "echo", "Hello, World from Docker")
)
```

It fails with: `msg="test.txt: no such file or directory"`

So after digging around a bit it seems I need to have `test.txt` in `target/docker/stage`. Then it works. But how do I get it there automatically? The file is actually in the root folder of the project.

Comment: I've been wondering this too. I can tell you that adding it as a mapping (`mappings in Docker` or `dockerPackageMappings in Docker`) does not work, despite it [seeming that should work](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/docker/DockerPlugin.scala#L94).

Answer (score 24):

I managed to get it to work by adding the file to `mappings in Universal`. So for you, you would need something like this:

```
mappings in Universal += file("test.txt") -> "keys/test.txt"
```

You won't need the `COPY` command if you do this, by the way.

Now, I'm not sure if this is going to add this mapping to other sbt-native-packager plugins. I hope a commenter can tell me whether or not this is true, but my intuition is that it will do so, which might be a dealbreaker for you. But any workaround is better than none, right? If you use `Build.scala` you could maybe use a VM argument to tell `sbt` whether or not to add this mapping...

Comment: I'm able to place files within the Docker working directory in this way, but unfortunately in the root. i.e. mapping to "/test.txt" seems to have the preceding slash ignored.

Comment: You could run another command to move the file where you want to:

dockerCommands += ExecCmd("RUN", "mv", s"${(defaultLinuxInstallLocation in Docker).value}/keys/test.txt", "/wherever/you/want/test.txt")

Comment: What is the base directory for these mappings? Like, relative to `build.sbt` in the root of the project, where would native packager look for `test.txt`?

Comment: @kag0 it's been 3 years since I wrote this answer (and 2.5 since I last worked on an sbt project) and I don't have access to the code anymore. So unfortunately I don't remember.

Comment: @2rs2ts I've figured it out through a bit of experimentation. The base directory is the project root (so same directory `build.sbt` is in). But do note that if you're in a sub-project, the base directory is still the same directory of the ROOT project `build.sbt`, not the subproject `build.sbt`.

Answer (score 13):

You may place all additional files (which must be included in container image) into folder `src/universal`. Content of that folder will be automatically copied in `/opt/app` folder within your container image. You don't need any additional configuration. See ["Getting started with Universal Packaging"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#getting-started-with-universal-packaging) for additional info.

The files located in `/src/universal` will be available in the runtime directory for the Scala app in the Docker container. This means that if your app has `/src/universal/example.txt`, then it can be accessed with `scala.io.Source.fromFile("./example.txt")`

Answer (score 4):

For **sbt-docker** plugin, not sbt-native-packager

I was able to add files this way:

For example, to add a file located in `src/main/resources/docker/some-file.ext`

```
dockerfile in docker := {
  val targetPath = "/usr/app"

  // map of (relativeName -> File) of all files in resources/docker dir, for convenience
  val dockerFiles = {
    val resources = (unmanagedResources in Runtime).value
    val dockerFilesDir = resources.find(_.getPath.endsWith("/docker")).get
    resources.filter(_.getPath.contains("/docker/")).map(r => dockerFilesDir.toURI.relativize(r.toURI).getPath -> r).toMap
  }

  new Dockerfile {
    from(s"$namespace/$baseImageName:$baseImageTag")
    ...
    add(dockerFiles("some-file.ext"), s"$targetPath/some-file.ext")
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a solution for sbt-docker plugin, not for sbt-native-packager.

Comment: Well it helped me, since I was trying to find a solution for sbt-docker and google brought me here.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working using `dockerPackageMappings`:

```scala
dockerPackageMappings in Docker += (baseDirectory.value / "docker" / "ssh_config") -> "ssh_config"

dockerCommands := (dockerCommands.value match {
  case Seq(from@Cmd("FROM", _), rest@_*) =>
    Seq(
     from,
     Cmd("Add", "ssh_config", "/sbin/.ssh/config")
  ) ++ rest
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entire directory to a Docker image's file system by first making it available using `dockerPackageMappings`, and then COPYing it as an additional Docker command.

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
dockerPackageMappings in Docker ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / ".." / "frontend" )

dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  Cmd("COPY", "frontend /opt/frontend"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to copy an entire folder/directory recursively you can also use the Universal plugin (similar to @2rs2ts answer). It has a helper method that will copy a local folder into the image.

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper.directory
Universal / mappings ++= directory("path/to/myFolder")
```

The **"path/to/folder"** is relative to your project root directory.

Directory will be copied to /opt/docker/myFolder in the target image